# What to do if I don't secure a PhD position (UK)?

Tags: phd, application, united-kingdom

I'm applying for PhD programs in CS/statistics next year in the UK, and am worried I might not secure a place (I'm at a weird position where I have weak grades, but a strong research proposal and good research experience but it's all individual and in preprint form), so I'd like to have some safety options.

I've thought of a few backup options, and was hoping for some advice on evaluating (1) whether these are really "backups", i.e. whether they're easier to get into than decent PhD programs and (2) what impact they would have on a future academic career, e.g. on applying again next year.

1. **Safety schools --** Are there any "safety schools" when it comes to PhDs (and if so, what is a decent safety school in the UK for a 2:1 or low 1st)? In particular, are lower-ranked schools (especially those with good departments/research groups in the areas I'm interested in) are easier to get in, and do grades matter more or less when applying to scuh schools?
2. **Other countries --** Are there any countries (preferably Europe) in which grades matter notably less in PhD admissions?
3. **Industry --** In particular **(1)** do grades matter more or less than academia in industry, especially industry "research labs" **(2)** will a year in industry or a gap year disadvantage me when applying next year for a PhD? For example, how might one get recommendation letters applying for a PhD after a year in industry? I would imagine trying to do some kind of research project under an academic during my year in industry, but typically PhD programs ask for 2-3 reference letters, so is it appropriate to ask my undergraduate professors for a reference letter again after a year in industry?
4. **Masters --** Is doing another Masters at all a good idea? In particular, do grades matter more or less than for a PhD? I imagine my research experience and proposal will matter less when applying for a Masters.
5. **Research assistant positions/anything else --** Are there any non-PhD research/teaching/any other positions in the UK? "Research assistant" positions are quite common in my home country for those without PhDs -- does the concept of joining and working for a research lab without a PhD exist in the UK?

A bit of a broad question, I apologise for that, but I think the sub-questions are related enough for practical purposes that I would hope it's OK to include them in one.

Comment: Please focus you question more, otherwise it will be probably closed due to being to broad.

Comment: A low 1st is not a bad grade.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that your approach to your future is too much predicated on the notion that it may be determined by mechanistic fulfilment of objective (almost “box-ticking”) criteria. You ask how to get recommendations, whether it is appropriate to ask people, do grades matter, almost as if you think there are standard approaches to life’s journey. There are not. I can only suggest that you communicate openly with those who are relevant to your aspirations,  that you make clear where your enthusiasms and competence lie, and that you seek personal adaptability to changing circumstances rather than seeking rules for handling them.